# Xamarin android button click to open watsapp chat form an app

Tags: android, xamarin, buttonclick

I have a code to open watsapp chat with a number when user click the button it will open watsapp application to chat with that number but my code is not working.

```
 button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.watsapp_op);
        // this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.watsapp_op).Click += this.Message;


        button.Click += delegate
        {

             Button1_Click();

        };
```

and this is a function code

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello");

        string phoneNumberWithCountryCode = "+923362315679";
        string message = "HI";

        StartActivity(new Intent(
        Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNumberWithCountryCode + "&text=" + message)));
    }
```

Comment: "not working" is never a helpful description of a problem.  Is it throwing an error?  An exception?  Does the app crash?  What exactly is it doing, or not doing?  What steps have you taken to debug your code and isolate the problem?

Comment: no, it doesn't give any error and also no app crashes. just nothing happens when clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below to send message, call the method in button click:

```
   private void OpenWhatsApp(Activity activity, string number, string message)
    {

        try
        {
            PackageManager pm = activity.PackageManager;
            Intent myintent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + URLEncoder.Encode(message, "UTF-8");
            myintent.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
            myintent.SetData(Uri.Parse(url));
            if (myintent.ResolveActivity(pm) != null)
            {
                activity.StartActivity(myintent);
            }
            else
            {
                //Error message
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // exception
        }

    }
```